# How much of our resources do we get back if we destroy a room?

Tags: warframe

Me and my clan mates plan on tearing down our dojo, and remaking it anew (as it is currently a big mess). But, do we get all of the resources from stuff we destroy (to the vault)? If not, how much of it?

We are a Shadow Clan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Warframe [wiki page](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Dojo):

> "Any resources that were initially spent to fund the room that was
>   destroyed (**including** Credits, Forma, or Platinum) will be refunded
>   **to the Clan Vault only**. Once refunded, these resources may be contributed by a Treasurer to fund research projects, new rooms, or
>   even the reconstruction of the destroyed room elsewhere for no
>   additional cost to clan members."

So only the clan gets the resources back and can use it to rebuild the Dojo. However, individual players do not get back the resources they've spent on the Dojo.

Comment: So the answer appears to be "Yes, you get all the resources back in full."